# Js prototype.forEach vs. Array.prototype.forEach.call vs. for

Tags: javascript, for-loop, optimization, foreach

I came across some discussion on a stackoverflow post a couple days back (sorry I cannot remember the post) where, someone suggested that forEach has a time penalty in comparison to for loop (i.e., takes more time to run). To test this, I wrote the following code:

```
    function testPrototypeUse(){
 /*
  * Checks whether there is a performance penalty in 
  * invoking prototype methods from builtin objects
  * specifically, forEach from Array.prototype
  */
 'use strict';
 const max_size = 3600000;
 let blob = [];
 let txt = '';
 for(let i=0; i<max_size; i++){
     blob.push(i);
 }
 console.log(''+ max_size +' checks for \'for\' and forEach');
 console.log('Initial blob size test: ' + blob.length);
 let start = process.hrtime();
 Array.prototype.forEach.call(blob, function(n){
     txt += n;
});
 let elapsed = process.hrtime(start);
 console.log('Array.prototype.forEach.call took: Total: '+ (elapsed[0]) +' s, ' + parseFloat(elapsed[1]/10e6).toPrecision(4) +' ms ');
 // delete txt; throws Syntax Error: cannot delete unqualified identifier
 txt = '';
 console.log('Blob size test before for: ' + blob.length);
 start = process.hrtime();
 for(let i=0; i<blob.length; i++){
     txt += i;
 }
 elapsed = process.hrtime(start);
 console.log('For loop took: Total: '+ (elapsed[0]) +' s, ' + parseFloat(elapsed[1]/10e6).toPrecision(4) +' ms ');
 txt = '';
 console.log('Blob size test before blob.forEach: ' + blob.length);
 start = process.hrtime();
 blob.forEach(function(i){ txt+=i; });
 elapsed = process.hrtime(start);
 console.log('blob.forEach took: Total: '+ (elapsed[0]) +' s, ' + parseFloat(elapsed[1]/10e6).toPrecision(4) +' ms ');

}
```

My initial thought before running the tests were as follows:

1. There will not be any significant performance penalty.
2. Array.prototype.forEach.call and blob.forEach would be slightly slower (if at all) than for. My understanding on this being that the creating a function stack and, looking up the prototype chain will add some extra overhead.

After running the test with values between 1000000 - 3600000, the results I got were:
[image]

Now, seeing the first 2 results were as I expected (although, the performance penalty was more than I expected for prototype.forEach than for). In case of `blob.forEach` the penalty was even higher (if I am right, because the compiler had to follow the entire prototype chain to the 2nd last, Array). I was wondering if, there was a any available optimization that can be employed to improve the performance of Array.prototype.forEach.call? I have been using them instead of for loop in my code and, seeing the difference, am worried about penalty when the code has to run under high stress environment.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A single run is hardly representative.

Comment: [Do not worry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) until your code actually runs in a high stress environment.